# how throw exception if decimal value is bigger than float in C#

Tags: c#

i want throw exception if value of decimal is bigger than float (without floating point)

this sample code below works fine (throw overflowException) for integer

```
decimal a = decimal.MaxValue;
int b = checked(int.Parse(a.ToString()));
```

but this sample code does not throw any exception

```
decimal a = decimal.MaxValue;
float b = checked(float.Parse(a.ToString())); // b is 7.92281625E+28
```

how find out if value of decimal is bigger than float(without floating point)?

Comment: The integral part of a decimal will always fit in a float.

Comment: What do you mean by `find out if value of decimal is bigger than float(without floating point)`? Do you want to throw away everything after the decimal point and compare the integer parts?

Comment: The max for a `float` is `3.402823E+38`. The max for a decimal is `79228162514264337593543950335`. The `decimal` can't be bigger than a `float`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int b = checked(int.Parse(a.ToString()));
```

is a very bad way of checking whether a value will cause an `OverflowException`, because you don't know how `a` will be represented as a string.

Instead, use a [cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions):

```
decimal d = decimal.MaxValue;

int i = (int)d;
// Throws OverflowException
```

As @Enigmativity and @CodeCaster pointed out in the comments, the integer part of a `decimal` will *always* fit in a `float`:

```
decimal d = decimal.MaxValue;

float i = (float)d;
// No problem!
```

You can use [decimal.Truncate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.truncate(v=vs.90).aspx) if you just need to remove the fractional part of a `decimal`.

Comment: He wants `float` instead. This code doesn't throw with a `float`.

Comment: thank you very much do you know any idea about second part of question? i am new in C#